# gotoAndStop deletes custom format on TLFTextField

Tags: flash, actionscript, tlf

I've defined two different parts on Flash Timeline, like:

- 'a', frames 1:10;
- 'b', frames 11:20;

which contains two different TLFTextFields. I set the format to both of them like Font, Size, Align, etc.

Whenever I do gotoAndStop('b') the TLFTextField that is in these frames is set to default, all the formats are lost.

Is it possible to keep the format I define on the designer (Flash Professional) so I can just edit text ???

edit: Problem does not exist whenever I work on smaller movieclip (with 2-3 differently labeled parts of frames in MC). Also does not happen whenever I try to reptoduce itin new, empty project.

Movieclip I have the problem with has over 20 parts with unique label on each. Even in debugging mode, right after 'gotoAndStop', I check the clip and its format is default (TNR, default size, alignment and other properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT! A solution to my problem was just as simple, as removing this.gotoAndStop('frame'); from Constructor and all the texts assignments.

Whenever you work with TLFTextFields - NEVER use gotoAndStop(); in constructors!!!!!